# using google cloud storage for 'attachments'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a (ndb.model) 'table' in app engine to which I need to add 'attachments' such as .jpg, .doc, xls and so on.  I cannot pre-determine what these files will be, it's up to the user.  This was reasonably easy using blobkey / blobstore but I am having trouble with Google Cloud Storage for this purpose.

my html is simple:

```
<label for="form_attach">Please select Attachment</label>
<input type="file" name="form_attach" id="form_attach" />
```

My Python code is also simple:

```
tempblob = self.request.get('form_attach')
logging.error(repr(tempblob))  -- shows the contents of tempblob
```

So... How do I know the content-type (mime type) of the incoming blob so that I can save it in Google Cloud Storage correctly?  I need to set the content-type when the blob is stored so that it will serve / display correctly.

gcs.stat(...).content_type looks like it's what I need but it requires a valid, stored, GCS file from which to retrieve the information.  Similarly Python's mimetypes needs a file name but I seem to retrieve the contents of the file.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://blog.whiteoctober.co.uk/2016/08/01/handling-uploads-with-app-engine-and-webapp2/

Comment: Thanks Jeff, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Jeff O'Neill's link provided the answers I was looking for, thanks.
Question will be closed.